# search filter with ListView reactNative

Tags: react-native, listview, axios, searchbar

hii i'm still new to react-native i'm trying to implement a search in the listview without Refetching the data (search by name ) 
like searching the json file i first fetched so
how can i make it works guys ? i followed many tutorials  but still can't do it the listView is allways empty 
here's my code i hope i found a solution for that

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, Image, ListView } from "react-native";
import axios from "axios";
import { SearchButton } from "./utilities/SearchButton";
import SearchBar from "react-native-searchbar";
class SearchScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.ds = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
    });
    this.state = {
      doctors: [],
      specefic: []
    };
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.fetchdata();
  }
  fetchdata = () => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:3000/api/Doctor")
      .then(response => this.setState({ doctors: response.data }));
  };
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
      headerRight: <SearchButton navigation={navigation} />
    };
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <View>
          <SearchBar
            ref={ref => (this.props.navigation.searchBar = ref)}
            data={this.state.doctors}
            handleResults={results => {
              this.setState({ specefic: results });
            }}
            iOSPadding={false}
            allDataOnEmptySearch={true}
            fontSize={23}
            hideBack={true}
            heightAdjust={-5}
          />
        </View>
        <View>
          <ListView
            enableEmptySections={true}
            dataSource={this.ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.doctors)}
            renderRow={service => {
              return (
                <View style={styles.box}>
                  <Image
                    style={styles.image}
                    source={{ uri: service.profileImageUrl }}
                  />
                  <View style={styles.boxContent}>
                    <Text style={styles.title}>{service.nom}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.description}>{service.email}</Text>
                  </View>
                </View>
              );
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default SearchScreen;
```

Comment: You can change use ListView  as Flatlist

Comment: @hongdevelop it didn't work either i don't know what i'm doing wrong so please could you help me with it

Comment: You need try `keyExtractor` from 'Flatlist`

Comment: where you have used `specific` state ?

Comment: @JaydeepGalani specific state ??

Comment: @hongdevelop i will try it thanx

Comment: this.state = {
      doctors: [],
      specefic: [] // this one
    };

Comment: @JaydeepGalani it's an empty array that will contain the result search here this.setState({ specefic: results });

Comment: I mean to display data where you are using it?

Comment: @JaydeepGalani ahh in this code i'am not using it cause i tried so many things and none of them works so i uploaded this code (clean xD)

Comment: your search results are in that state, you are not using it so how do a listview will change?

Comment: i don't know exactly how to use them in the listview even i've watched some videos nothing have worked